# What is wrong in my code. Decryption.txt not accepting any message in java file operation.?

Tags: java, file, buffer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class EncryptDecryptFile{

public String readEncryptionFile()
{
    String contentLine1 = "";
    //String encryptFilename = Solution.filepath + "EncryptionFile.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {   
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\EncryptionFile.txt"));      
        String contentLine = br.readLine();
        while (contentLine != null)
        {
            contentLine1 = contentLine;
            
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            if(br != null)
            br.close();
               
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
             System.out.println("Error in closing the BufferedReader");
        }
      }
    
      return contentLine1;
   }

public void writeDecryptionFile(String message)  
{
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    //String decryptFilename = Solution.filepath + "DecryptionFile.txt";
    try
    {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\DecryptionFile.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(message);
            }
            else
            {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(message);
            }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    { 
        try
        {
             if(bw!=null)
             bw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
               System.out.println("Error in closing the BufferedWriter"+ex);
        }
     }  
  }

 }


public class Solution {
  public static String filepath = "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\";

  private static String generateString()
  {
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder generatedString = new StringBuilder(20);
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        generatedString.append(c);
    }
    return generatedString.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = sc.nextLine();

    try{
        EncryptDecryptFile f = new EncryptDecryptFile ();

        String encryptFilename = Solution.filepath + "EncryptionFile.txt";
        String generatedString = generateString();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\EncryptionFile.txt"));
        writer.write(generatedString);
        writer.close();

        if(f.readEncryptionFile().equals(generatedString))
        {
            
            f.writeDecryptionFile(message);
            
            String decryptFilename = Solution.filepath + "DecryptionFile.txt";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\DecryptionFile.txt"));
            String messageFromFile = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();

            System.out.println(messageFromFile);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

  }

 }
```

1. When I write in the **Decryption.txt** file using **writeDecryptionFile(message)** method the file not accept the message.
2. There are two method **readEncryptionFile()** method and **writeDecryptionFile(message)** method.
3. **readEncryptionFile()** read the content from **Encryption.txt** and it matches with **generatedString** if it equals true then,
4. **writeDecryptionFile(message)** method write the message **String message = sc.nextLine();** to the **Decryption.txt** file.

Comment: Are you sure about file extensions .txt?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this you can use library to decrypt and encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you are trying to ask, but it seem's like you are missing a 'flush' in writeDecryptionFile

```
...
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(message);
bw.flush();
...
```

without the flush the buffered characters are never written to the stream
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()